# Docker-compose's mariadb cannot reboot after change (exit code 1)

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, reboot

I'm studying docker-compose with this github.
https://github.com/lusehair/42inception.git

(It works well in Ubuntu. Please run in Ubuntu when you want to run!)
In first, it works well.
But if i edit a page and reboot, there is an error.
(`docker-compose down` in other terminal, `sudo systemctl stop mysql` to turn off mysql.)
: I thought `sudo systemctl stop mysql` could stop my mariadb service. But if not, please tell me in comment.

```
srcs_mariadb_1 exited with code 1
srcs_mariadb_1 exited with code 1
srcs_mariadb_1 exited with code 1
srcs_mariadb_1 exited with code 1
...
```

I think this has caused because `~/data/` folder hasn't deleted well.
But i don't want to delete data folder.
I want to maintain wp changes if i reboot docker-compose, even Ubuntu!

Edit : things in comment
Q. Why do i run my docker-compose program in Ubuntu only?
A. I know it is logical problem that launching docker only in Ubuntu OS. But i said like this because of two reasons. First, some of my command should be launched in linux os. Second, my subject requires me to launch my docker-compose project in a Virtual Machine. I choosed Ubuntu for that.

I also tried to debug more specifically, like below.
BEFORE START (BASIC):
: Run `make` in root directory.
 It cleans docker & data folder, setup, and build.

- `docker-compose up mariadb`
  I'm afraid why this works well...

```
kkim@kkim-VirtualBox:~/inception/lusehair/srcs$ docker-compose up mariadb
Creating network "srcs_vpcbr" with driver "bridge"
Creating srcs_mariadb_1 ... done
Attaching to srcs_mariadb_1
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:18:52 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 8 ...
kkim@kkim-VirtualBox:~/inception/lusehair/srcs$
```

- `docker-compose up wordpress`
  I tried after `docker-compose up mariadb` has succeeded.
  This gave me the problem.
  It was something diffrent with other error.
  It keep trying to attach for several minutes. I stopped this almost after 10 minutes.

```
kkim@kkim-VirtualBox:~/inception/lusehair/srcs$ docker-compose up wordpress
srcs_mariadb_1 is up-to-date
Creating srcs_wordpress_1 ... done
Attaching to srcs_wordpress_1
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping srcs_wordpress_1 ... done
```

- `docker-compose up mariadb wordpress`
  It gave me error as usually it does.. :(

```
kkim@kkim-VirtualBox:~/inception/lusehair/srcs$ docker-compose up mariadb wordpress
srcs_mariadb_1 is up-to-date
Starting srcs_wordpress_1 ... done
Attaching to srcs_mariadb_1, srcs_wordpress_1
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:18:52 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 8 ...
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:18:56 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 8 ...
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:18:59 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 9 ...
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:19:02 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 9 ...
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:19:06 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 8 ...
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:19:11 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 8 ...
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:19:17 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 7 ...
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:19:26 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 9 ...
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:19:41 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 8 ...
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:20:10 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 9 ...
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:21:04 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 9 ...
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:22:06 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 8 ...
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:23:09 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 8 ...
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:24:12 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 7 ...
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:25:15 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 8 ...
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:26:18 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 8 ...
srcs_mariadb_1 exited with code 1
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-27 17:28:24 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 7 ...
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping srcs_wordpress_1 ... done
Stopping srcs_mariadb_1   ... done
```

Thank you for reading until this.
I have connected to git repository's owner, but it's working well in his ubuntu.
I will try to reinstall my os and wrote in this question.

Please tell me if i'm misunderstanding something!!!
I think i am, but i don't know the point.

This is docker-compose.yml.
It uses local images (Dockerfile) only.

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:inc
        volumes:
            - ~/data/maria:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
            MARIA_LOGIN: "${MARIA_LOGIN}"
            MARIA_PASS: "${MARIA_PASS}"
        ports: 
            - "3306:3306"
        build:
            context: ./requirements/mariadb
            dockerfile: Dockerfile 
        networks:
            vpcbr:
        env_file: .env
               

    wordpress:
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
        image: wordpress:inc
        volumes:
            - ~/data/wp:/var/www/wordpress
        restart: always
        environment:
            WP_LOGIN: "${WP_LOGIN}"
            WP_PASS: "${WP_PASS}"
            WPU_1LOGIN: "${WPU_1LOGIN}"
            WPU_1PASS: "${WPU_1PASS}"
            MARIA_LOGIN: "${MARIA_LOGIN}"
            MARIA_PASS: "${MARIA_PASS}"
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        build:
            context: ./requirements/wordpress
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        networks:
            vpcbr:
        env_file: .env
    nginx:
        image: nginx:inc
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - wordpress
        ports:
             - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ~/data/wp:/var/www/wordpress
        build:
            context: ./requirements/nginx
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        networks:
            vpcbr:
        extra_hosts:
            - "lusehair.42.fr:127.0.0.1"
        env_file: .env

networks:
    vpcbr:
        driver: bridge
```

And this is Mariadb's Dockerfile, setup.sh.
You can see all project files in github.

```
FROM debian:buster 

MAINTAINER lusehair <lusehair@42.student.fr>

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mariadb-server vim procps; 

COPY tools/setup.sh . 
RUN chmod +x setup.sh 

EXPOSE 3306
RUN rm /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf 
# Swith off the bind address 
COPY tools/50-server.cnf /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d 
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/setup.sh"]
```

```
if [ ! -d "/var/lib/mysql/wordpress" ]; then 
    
    mysql_install_db
    service mysql start
    
    mysql -e "CREATE USER '${MARIA_LOGIN}'@'localhost' identified by '${MARIA_PASS}';" &&\
    mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS wordpress;" &&\
    mysql -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '${MARIA_LOGIN}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MARIA_PASS}';" &&\
    mysql -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
    service mysql stop 
fi
#sleep 5
mysqld
```

Comment: 1) What does stopping a local mysql service has to do with your mariadb container service in docker-compose ? 2) Why would we have to launch those compose services in a docker install in ubuntu ? One point of docker is to launch those services anywhere a docker engine is available. 3) And most importantly: what is your exact question ?  If you are expecting us to guess what changes you have made and what errors are shown in your failed mariadb container logs, I'm pretty sure no one here has extralucent powers. Please [edit your question](/posts/68152446/edit) with debugging details

Comment: @Zeitounator
1) I thought ```sudo systemctl stop mysql``` can close mariadb too. But if is wrong, tell me!
2) I know it is logical problem that launching docker only in Ubuntu OS.
   But i said like this because of two reasons.
   First, some of my command could launch in linux os.
   Second, my subject requires me to launch my docker-compose project in a Virtual Machine. I choosed Ubuntu for that.
3) I want to know exactly why it has stopped in terminal, but it just gave me "srcs_mariadb_1 exited with code 1" only. Can you tell me that is there any other ways to debug more specifically?

Comment: `Can you tell me that is there any other ways to debug more specifically?` => `docker-compose up mariadb`

Comment: @Zeitounator I edited my question as you said! Summary, ```docker-compose up mariadb``` **worked well** (I dont know why). but after success, ```docker-compose up wordpress``` (depends on mariadb) gave me new error. And ```docker-compose up mariadb wordpress``` occured error as normally. 

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to expose 3306 port.

Your `setup.sh` creates a different user to that one that it gives grants to. Containers aren't good for running services.

There's a good case for using the official images.

```
version: '3'
services:
    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:10.5.11
        volumes:
            - ~/data/maria:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
            MARIADB_USER: "${MARIA_LOGIN}"
            MARIADB_PASSWORD: "${MARIA_PASS}"
            MARIADB_DATABASE: wordpress
```

Don't get as many errors/learning things however :-)

From your repository it looks like you resolved the rest too (include wordpress which is an official image).